# How to make the Rails asset pipeline Gzip images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, pipeline, assets

How can I get the Rails asset pipeline to Gzip compress images? It compresses css and js files but not images.

**EDIT**

Rewritten question. Initially this was about subfolders but it seems Rails isn't compressing any images.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to gzip already-compressed files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [section 4.1.2 in the canonical Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets):

> When files are precompiled, Sprockets also creates a gzipped (.gz) version of your assets.

To precompile your assets, use the bundled rake task:

```
# from command line
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

**UPDATE**:

After some research into the subject, I've allegorically found that, while Sprockets compresses JS and CSS assets, it does *not* compress *images*. Then I came across this gem: [sprockets-image_compressor](https://github.com/botandrose/sprockets-image_compressor)

I haven't implemented it myself, but it claims to provide lossless compression of image assets using [pngcrush](http://pmt.sourceforge.net/pngcrush/) and [jpegoptim](https://github.com/tjko/jpegoptim). Interestingly, the docs state the following:

> If the environment doesn't have pngcrush and/or jpegoptim installed, the gem will fall back on binaries packaged with the gem.

Again, I haven't used this myself, but if it does what it claims, it might be exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: That doesnt really help. I know it does that. What I am saying is that when I run that it doesn't gzip images in subfolders.

Comment: Hmm, seems it isn't even compressing any images.

Comment: Yes – this seems to be the default behavior of Sprockets. I've updated my answer with a potential fix.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't compress any images because images are already compressed (like jpeg). So it is not needed for traffic saving purposes.

Which means you cannot do it with any of existing settings.

Comment: What about SVG images? There seems to be no way to gzip them using the assets pipeline.

Comment: thanks! perhaps it's the best way, especially when images are hosted in cloud (S3 for example) and no way to gzip them on the fly using web browser.

Comment: That is actually very wrong, You reduce the size of a JPEG a lot by just using lossless compression algorithms.

Comment: @FrancisMalloch Rails asset pipeline cannot compress images, so was the question.